# Vertical takeoff for a DJI Matrice 100

Tags: dji-sdk

`DJI Android SDK version: 4.11`

`Matrice 100` / `Matrice 600`

I am trying to take off the drone vertically.

I tried with `GoToAction` in a timeline, but that failed due to some bug in the SDK, (confirmed by your support team dev@dji.com #29496) I get STARTED for the GoToAction, but no PROGRESSED or FINISHED, and no errors logged at all.

Since I need to continue working, I tried a workaround by sending FlightControlData to the VirtualStick by calling the following function with the requested height 20 times a second:

```
VerticalControlMode.POSITION
FlightOrientationMode.AIRCRAFT_HEADING
VirtualStickModeEnabled = true
VirtualStickAdvancedModeEnabled = true

void sendHeightCommand(Float requestedAltitude) {
    FlightControlData data = new FlightControlData(0f, 0f, 0f, requestedAltitude);
    flightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(data, djiError -> {
        log.v(djiError.getDescription);
    });
}
```

And it works (with the right amount of timeouts) but if there is wind, the drone drifts away, which is very dangerous for me as there is more than one drone in the field, and I don't want them to collide.

Is there another way to change the altitude of the drone, while maintaining its position?
Or is there a way to measure the wind, and push back against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution was to use the function: [`setVirtualStickAdvancedModeEnabled(true)`](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=takeoff&i=4&#djiflightcontroller_setvirtualstickadvancedmodeenabled_inline)

The reason I didn't see any results was because in the simulator I was playing with 20.0 North Wind, which apparently is too much.

When I lowered it to 5.0 it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[*] Take off drone vertically:

I always use the TakeOffAction in the timelineMission before the GoToAction to ascend to the desired height. However I'm using a Mavic Pro and the SDK may behave different with a matrice drone.

When using the FlightControlData with the VirtualSticks, I use the `startPrecisionTakeoff()` method in the `FlightController` class; after the takeoff, the drone ascends to the desired position when the flight control data is sent continuously.

[*] stable hovering:

For the hovering the only low cost solution I see is to enable the VisionAssistedPositioning in the `FlightAssistant` class, I don't know if the Matrice supports this feature as the documentation doesn't say anything on the supported aircrafts.

Comment: The Mavic pro works flawlessly, also the P4A. but the Matrice 100 & 600 don't.

`startPrecisionTakeoff` returns error: The feature is unsupported.